# PL/SQL Switching two columns from two tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk-load

Suppose I have two tables (tblA and tblB) and want to switch the second column of each table (tblA.Grade and tblB.Grade) as shown:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|    table a               table b    |
+-------------------------------------+
| name  grade           name    grade |
| a     60              f       50    |
| b     45              g       70    |
| c     30              h       90    |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Now, I would like to switch the grade column from table a to table b and the the grade column from table b to table a.  The result should look like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|      table a               table b      |
+-----------------------------------------+
|     name  grade           name    grade |
|     a     50              f       60    |
|     b     70              g       45    |
|     c     90              h       30    |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I have created the tables, loaded them into cursors using bulk collect and the following code to complete the transformation:

```
insert into tblA values('a',60);
insert into tblA values('b',45);
insert into tblA values('c',30);
insert into tblb values('f',70);
insert into tblb values('g',80);
insert into tblb values('h',90);
```

.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE tbla_type IS TABLE OF tbla%ROWTYPE;
    l_tbla tbla_type;
    TYPE tblb_type IS TABLE OF tblb%ROWTYPE;
    l_tblb tblb_type;

BEGIN
-- All rows at once...
SELECT *
BULK COLLECT INTO l_tbla
FROM tbla;

SELECT *
BULK COLLECT INTO l_tblb
FROM tblb;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_tblb.COUNT);

    FOR indx IN 1 .. l_tbla.COUNT
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_tbla(indx).lname);
        update tbla set grade = l_tblb(indx).grade 
          where l_tbla(indx).lname= tbla.lname;

              update tblb set grade = l_tbla(indx).grade 
          where l_tblb(indx).lname= tblb.lname;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

So, although I did the task, I am wondering if there is a more simple solution that I have not thought of?

Please let me know if anyone knows if there may be a more simple solution?

Comment: Please fix your formatting by indenting all code and tables with four spaces.

Comment: Thanks N Din.  I had a few questions.  In the script you posted, it doesn't look like there is any sorting during your `bulk collect`s.  Do you care which `grade` is associated to which `name` after the swap?  If you are looking to simplify, is `PL/SQL` a requirement for you, or will plain `SQL` suffice?  What do you want to do if the tables have different numbers of rows?

Comment: Thanks,  I suppose the intent was that the grades of the first records would get switched and then the second and so on until one of the tables ran out of more records.

Comment: Hi,  sql is fine also, pl/sql is not a requirement.  I hit <enter> and cut my reply.  But I would add that grades for 'a' and 'f' would change, then grades for 'b' and 'g'.   Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is nothing called `first` or `second` record in databases as there is no guarantee that the first record entered will be the first one returned. So there should always be an `order by` to decide first/second etc.

So assuming you want the records to be ordered by `name` and then swap grade of smallest name of first table with grade of smallest name of second table,

Now assuming you fix the order thingy in your existing code, and if it is working, I believe it would be faster than the way I would do it below. Something like

1. Create a temp table and put names and grade ordered by name.

Reason of using temp table is mostly because later if I want to correct or revert the data, I can use the same temp table to reverse the merge.

```
    create table tmp1 as
    with ta as
    (select t.* ,
    row_number() over (order by name) as rnk
    from tblA t)
    ,tb as
    (select t.* ,
    row_number() over (order by name) as rnk
    from tblb t)
    select ta.name as ta_name,ta.grade as ta_grade,
    tb.name as tb_name,tb.grade as tb_grade
    from ta inner join tb
    on ta.rnk=tb.rnk
```

Output of `tmp1`

```
+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| TA_NAME | TA_GRADE | TB_NAME | TB_GRADE |
+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| a       |       60 | f       |       70 |
| b       |       45 | g       |       80 |
| c       |       30 | h       |       90 |
+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

Then use `merge` to swap value from `tmp1`.

```
merge  into tbla t1
using  tmp1 t
on (t1.name=t.ta_name)
when matched then update
set t1.grade=t.tb_grade;

merge  into tblb t1
using  tmp1 t
on (t1.name=t.tb_name)
when matched then update
set t1.grade=t.ta_grade;
```

If satisfied with result, drop the temp table later

```
drop table tmp1;
```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply folks.  This shows another way to complete the task.